# prepareForSegue function not being called in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am having a slight issue with the prepareForSegue function. It's not even printing out the println() statement. All I have is a basic button presenting another view controller modally. I have done this many times before so I have no idea what is going on?

Here is the absolute barebones:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    println("Segue Performed")
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMPLETE rookie mistake I made. I forgot to hook up the view controller to the storyboard view controller... Thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: SAVED ME THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the `prepareForSegue` method has been updated as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

That change is part of a wider "fix" on method signatures done from beta 5, with the goal of removing ambiguity on optionals and non optionals. So whenever an overridden class method is not called, most likely is because its signature has been changed.